# Changing the axis range dynamically doesnt refresh the lineplot but only the axis labels

Tags: ilnumerics

I am trying to change the axes Min and Max properties to show only the plot points that lie in a particular range.

say If I have lineplot whose X values are ranging from 0 to 100, I want to display only the values that are greater than 50.However I noticed that the lineplot is drawn using all the position points.Only the x axis ticks got renamed such that they start from 50 and end at 100.

The following is the code I am using

```
var axes = m_plotCube.First<ILAxisCollection>();
if (axes != null)
{
 ILAxis xAxis = axes.Where<ILAxis>(item => item.Label.Text == "X Axis").First();
 xAxis.Min = 50;
 xAxis.Max = 100;
 xAxis.Configure();
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I figured out that the trick is to use the plot cube limits intead of axis limits.but stuck with another issue. If I use the plotcube reference obtained by find query, there is no effect.

Comment: ILPlotCube pc =  new ILPlotCube {new ILLinePlot(A.T)};
    ILScene scene = new ILScene();
    scene.Add(pc);
    ilPanel2.Scene = scene;

    // DOES NOT WORK
    //var testPC = ilPanel1.Scene.Find<ILPlotCube().First();
           
    // DOES WORK                                                 pc.Limits.XMin = 3.5f;
pc.Limits.XMax = 10;
ilPanel2.Configure(); }'

Comment: please open a new question for the new issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ILPlotCube.Limits instead:

```
var pc = ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>();
pc.Limits.Set(
    new Vector3(50, pc.Limits.YMin, pc.Limits.ZMin),
    new Vector3(100, pc.Limits.YMax, pc.Limits.ZMax));
```

BTW: the axes are accessed much easier: `plotcube.Axes.XAxis` ...